# How to switch between 3 class names at an interval of 5 seconds infinitely

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How do I infinitely switch different class names on an element with an interval of 5 seconds like this:

By default, at 0 seconds, the element has a class name of 'banner-1' like this: `<div classname="hero banner-1">Hero</div>`

At 5 seconds, the element has a class name of 'banner-2' and 'active' like this: `<div classname="hero banner-2 active">Hero</div>`

At 10 seconds, the element has a class name of 'banner-3' and 'active' like this: `<div classname="hero banner-3 active">Hero</div>`

At 15 seconds, the element goes back to the default class name of only 'banner-1' like this: `<div classname="hero banner-1">Hero</div>`

At 20 seconds, the element has a class name of 'banner-2' and 'active' like this: `<div classname="hero banner-2 active">Hero</div>`

And it goes on like that infinitely for 25, 30, 35 seconds with an interval of 5 seconds infinitely.

Using Jquery, I have been able to do this but it's not working well and I am not sure how I have to go about the logic to include the third class and make it work perfectly:

```
setInterval(function() {
    if($('.hero').hasClass('banner-2 active')) {
      $('.hero').addClass("banner-3 active").removeClass("banner-2");
    } else {
      $('.hero').addClass("banner-2 active").removeClass("banner-3");
    }
  }, 5000)
```

How do I achieve it correctly javascript?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: @freedomn-m, I used this but it didn't turn out well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vanilla JS:

Change 1000 to 5000 in your code

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  const ele = document.querySelector('.hero');
  let cnt = 1;
  setInterval(function() {
    ele.classList.remove("banner-" + cnt);
    cnt++;
    if (cnt > 3) cnt = 1;
    ele.classList.add("banner-" + cnt);
    ele.classList.toggle("active", !ele.classList.contains("banner-1"));
  }, 1000);
});
```

```css
.banner-1 {
  color: green;
}

.banner-2 {
  color: blue;
}

.banner-3 {
  color: red;
}

.active {
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero banner-1">Hero</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
var arr = ["banner-1", "banner-2", "banner-3"]
var ele = $('.hero');
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    var c = ele.attr("class").split(' ')[1];
    var i = arr.indexOf(c) + 1;
    ele.removeClass(c);
    ele.addClass((i == arr.length ? arr[0] : arr[i]))
  }, 5000);
});
```

**Demo**

```js
var arr = ["banner-1", "banner-2", "banner-3"]
var ele = $('.hero');
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    var c = ele.attr("class").split(' ')[1];
    var i = arr.indexOf(c) + 1;
    ele.removeClass(c + " active");
    ele.addClass((i == arr.length ? arr[0] : arr[i] + " active"))
  }, 5000);
});
```

```css
.banner-1{color: yellow}
.banner-2{color: blue}
.banner-3{color: red}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hero banner-1">Hero</div>
```

Comment: [You forgot the .active](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64661310/295783)

Comment: @mplungjan Thanks, totally missed that :)

Comment: @mplungjan - How would I add a fade to this so the image transition isn't so abrupt?

Comment: @Rocky Add a transition to the class you toggle to

Comment: @mplungjan You're saying to add a transition to the banner-1, banner-2, banner-3 classes?

Comment: Just have one active class with transition

Answer (score 0):

As you havent provided what you've tried and thus nothing for us to provide feedback on, I'm going to give you some example code for you to turn into an actual solution:

```
let currentActive = 1; // remember where we are now
const maxItems = 3; // how many items?

setInterval(
    function(){
        // - remove 'active' from the currentActive element
        currentActive++;
        // if the currentActive > maxitems, set it back to 1
        // - add 'active' to the new currentActive element
    }, 
    5000
);
```

Comment: I don't really understand this well. I have just added what I have tried up there

Answer (score 0):

Will this work for you. The timer adds the class based on a class array. I have added some background colors to see it working. (Default don't have `.active` class )

```js
var arrClass = ["banner-1", "banner-2 active", "banner-3 active"];

var counter = 0;

setInterval(function() {
  // remove all class and add new class
  $("#hero").removeClass("banner-1 banner-2 banner-3 active").addClass(arrClass[counter]);
  
  // reset or increment counter
  counter = counter >= 3 ? 0 : counter + 1
}, 5000);
```

```css
.banner-1 {
  background-color: red;
}

.banner-2 {
  background-color: blue;
}

.banner-3 {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="hero" class="hero banner-1">Hero</div>
```

Comment: @Idris A different approach than other answers :). Good to know it worked